# Not always seeing output from PowerShell warning stream in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm attempting to run the following command in PowerShell through my C# application.

```
PsSession.RunPowerShellScript("Get-Mailboxstatistics -Identity John.Doe");
```

The method `RunPowerShellScript` returns a concatenated string of the output and looks like this.

```
public static string RunPowerShellScript(string psScript)
{
    try
    {
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.Runspace = psRunSpace; //Set Statically Elsewhere
        ps.AddScript(psScript);

        Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();

        if (ps.HadErrors)
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach (ErrorRecord errorRecord in ps.Streams.Error)
                output += errorRecord.Exception.Message.ToString();
            throw new Exception(output);
        }
        else
        {
            if (results.Count != 0)
            {
                string output = "";
                foreach (PSObject result in results)
                    output += result.BaseObject.ToString();
                return output;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ps.Streams.Warning.Count != 0)
                {
                    string output = "";
                    foreach (WarningRecord s in ps.Streams.Warning)
                        output += s.Message.ToString();
                    return output;
                }
                else
                    return "No Results.";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

The problem is when the `Get-MailboxStatistics` cmdlet returns a warning, `ps.Streams.Warning.Count` still equals 0 (actually *all* streams.count = 0).

However, if I run

```
PsSession.RunPowerShellScript("Write-Warning 'Test'")
```

then it returns the warning ("Test") properly.

I tried redirecting the warning stream to the output stream, by running this

```
PsSession.RunPowerShellScript("Get-Mailboxstatistics -Identity John.Doe  *>&1");
```

but that doesn't fix it.

If I run the cmdlet from the PowerShell ISE I get the following

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Mailboxstatistics -Identity John.Doe
WARNING: The user hasn't logged on to mailbox 'John.Doe'...
```

Comment: Are you using implicit remoting in your script?

Comment: I may not be familiar with that term, but after a which google search I'd say I think I am. I'm connecting to Exchange Online by creating a session then importing the session. (This is inside the psRunSpace object above, my idea being I can create the session once, then use it as needed.)

Comment: I've run into issues capturing warnings and errors working in that environment. The -WarningVariable  and -ErrorVariable common parameters don't work either.  The only workaround I've found is to use Start-Transcript, and then parse the warning messages out of the transcript file. I suspect it's related to the NoLanguage constraints of the exchange sessions, and the fact that you aren't really running cmdlets, but proxy functions.

Comment: Would this only affect the warning stream? The error stream populates when there are errors.

Comment: If you have found an answer for this, can you please do a self-post of an Answer block. People would like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran in the same issue and I decided to use -WarningAction Stop, then parse the exception message.